# How can I add volt syntax checking in PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm, phalcon, volt

I want to be able to have syntax highlighting in PHPStorm for Volt, Phalcon's template engine.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

In PHPStorm, click `File -> Settings`

On the left side of the options click `Editor -> File Types`

On the list that appears on the right, scroll down and select `Twig`

In the bottom panel, click the `+` button to add a new wildcard and add

`*.volt`

Click OK and then OK again.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on a `.volt` file in the project tab. Click on `associate with a file type`. Choose `twig`.