# Syntax highlighting for Volt in Notepad++

Tags: syntax-highlighting, phalcon, volt

I have just started using Phalcon and am amazed by it's versatitlity (previously used CakePHP). However, to make effective use of their **Volt** language I need syntax highlighting for it in Notepad++ but cannot find it anywhere.

Can anyone direct me to a package to install to introduce syntax highlighting for this language in Notepad++?

**Alternative**

I realise that such a package may not exist for Volt in Notepad++ yet. In that case can anyone suggest:

a) an alternative text editor that does have syntax highlighting for Volt (preferably as minimalistic and simple as Notepad++); or

b) a guide that would help get me started on making the xml file to enable syntax highlighting for Volt in Notepad++ (I've got a bit of time, no harm in trying...).

**Almost solution**

The answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576146/how-can-i-add-volt-syntax-checking-in-phpstorm) implies that **Twig** is similar to **Volt**.

Using [this](https://github.com/Banane9/notepadplusplus-twig) definition for Twig and assigning it to .volt extensions currently. However, if a better version exists that would be good (i.e. one which keeps the normal syntax highlighting for the HTML but also adds in keyword, comments, etc. highlighting for the Volt parts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used twig syntax highlighting with Aptana and it worked alright.

You could also look in to [Atom](http://atom.io) where there is a volt syntax available [language-volt](https://atom.io/packages/language-volt).

Comment: Ironically, I switched from Aptana to Notepad++ recently because I liked the more minimalistic feel. I'm downloading Atom to try out now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Atom](http://atom.io/) for pretty much everything. It supports the volt syntax as well as a bunch of other useful plugins / extensions.